# Haskell Travis CI show build logs

Tags: haskell, cabal, travis-ci

When I use Travis CI to build my Haskell project, it [fails](https://travis-ci.org/talklibre/talklibre/builds/39385415) to build and mentions a log file:

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies --enable-tests
...
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /home/travis/.cabal/logs/haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.log ):
```

My `.travis.yml` file is

```
language: haskell
ghc: 7.8
```

My `.cabal` file is on [GitHub here](https://github.com/talklibre/talklibre/blob/f26351962e4a9f015cb94dd7feb99dd50111a04c/talklibre.cabal).

How do I view the whole log file? Or, how do I configure cabal to output the log to standard output?

Comment: I can almost guarantee you forgot to install alex & happy

Comment: @alternative Thank you for the tip, I did find that adding 
"cabal install happy-1.19.4" fixed it. It's strange because I don't need to do that on my machine even though I'm using a sandbox. What do you mean by "forgot to install"?

Comment: You don't have to on your machine because `happy` and `alex` are both executables, not libraries - as long as they are somewhere in your `PATH` (which they likely are on your own machine, from haskell platform or whatever) then you don't have to worry about them. This is also why `cabal` doesn't install them as dependencies. Basically, whenever `haskell-src-exts` fails to install, its almost always `happy` and `alex` missing (this issue comes up alot in irc it seems)

Comment: I found this article about the problem: http://ro-che.info/articles/2014-03-08-happy-alex-ghc-7.8.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can view it as Travis likely deletes the virtual machine as soon as it's done building.

You might get more info if you run `cabal install` with `--verbose` (`-v`).

Alternatively, since Travis allows you to run arbitrary shell commands, you can take advantage of that and use `cat` to dump the log file(s) to standard output:

```
if ! cabal install --only-dependencies --enable-tests; then
    cat "$HOME"/.cabal/logs/haskell-src-exts-*.log
    exit 1
fi
```